# set name of many textctrl itering in range

Tags: python, wxpython

please i want to put several textctrl in a panel and im trying to set the names and positions  dynamically, with the following code,controls appears but i cant assing the names.

```
        p=0
    for i in range(20):
        p += 25
        indesc ="ingdesc"
        indesc = indesc + str(i)
        print indesc

        self.HERE I WANT TO PUT indesc value = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel,pos=(280,190+p),size=(350,23),style=wx.TE_READONLY)
```

thanks

Comment: Do you mean to set the visible content of the `TextCtrl`?

Comment: no, i wanna set the value of ingdesc variable to the name of attribute self.***        . in way to name each textctrl itering too, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
import wx

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title='Indesc')
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        textctrls=[]
        for i in range(20):
            textctrls.append("self.indesc"+str(i))
        p=0
        for i in range(20):
            p+=25
            textctrls[i] = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel,pos=(10,10+p),size=(350,23),style=wx.TE_READONLY)
        textctrls[0].SetValue("Item 0")
        textctrls[11].SetValue("Item 11")
        self.Show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MainFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

[image]

But and it's a big BUT you are making life difficult for yourself because you can't access the items by the string name `self.indesc11` for example you have to refer to it by the position in the `list` (as far as I can tell).
It is sensible and clearer for the future, if you are explicit when coding this sort of thing. It's only copy and paste after all.